# Mouseover event handler brings up both divs when I want only one

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, mouseevent

I am trying to do a mouseover event for one picture where when you mouseover a div comes up and animates on the picture. When I do my mouseover though, it brings up both divs for separate pictures when I only want one at a time. Here is my code. The first part is the mouseover. Second is mouseout.

```
$('.portfolio img').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
    $(this).parent().find('img:first').stop().animate({opacity:1}, 800, function() {
          $("div.folio").animate({ height: '+=25px', top: '-=24px' }, 100, function() {
                $("div.folio span").animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500);
          });
    });
});

$('.img_grayscale').mouseout(function(){
       $(this).stop().animate({opacity:0}, 800, function() {
            $("div.folio span").animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500, function() {
                $("div.folio").animate({ height: '-=25px', top: '+=24px' }, 100);
                $("div.folio").css('top', '-9px');
            });
        });
}); 

        <div class="portfolio">
            <h2>The Portfolio</h2>
            <p class="slideTwo">Check out some of our recent projects.</p>
            <ul>
                <li><img src="portfolioOne.jpg"></img><div class="folio"><span>thesite.com</span></div></li>
                <li><img src="portfolioOne.jpg"></img><div class="folio"><span>mysite.com</span></div></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: It would help to see a functional website, or a copy on jsFiddle.

Comment: I am doing this on my local environment right now. I should though put this on my git repo in a sub directory.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery's `$("div.folio")` will return all divs with a class of "folio".  Since you are seeing this animation on both images, rather than just the one you've moused-over, I'm assuming they both have the same class on the div they want to animate.  In order to only animate one, you'll need to be more specific when selecting it with jQuery.  Including $(this)  on the path to the div to animate usually works, but I can't tell you the exact code without the corresponding HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel the bubble up event by returning "false" from your event handler.

```
$('.portfolio img').mouseover(function(){
    // Your logic here...
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of concerns that I have about this which may or may not be problematic depending on what else is going on that you haven't shown.

- You're doing `$(this).parent().find('img:first')` inside of a jQuery onmouseover function where `$(this)` should already be representing the `img` that you care about. Did you find that was necessary for some reason?
- You could be more specific in your selector. Try doing `$(".portfolio>ul>li>img")`
- `img_grayscale` is only mentioned once in your markup in your question so I'm not sure how that class gets applied but I'm assuming it does.
- You could just add the class `portfolio` (or some unique identifier) to your images directly and probably have an easier time figuring out exactly why it isn't working as you expect. Then your mouseover selector could just be `$(".specialClass")`

You should definitely try posting a jsfiddle.net; you could borrow any two images off the web for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure this one out. I had to basically transverse the DOM through the following code. I referenced the image and then I went to the parent then to the next element in the DOM which was my div of div.folio. Then I went to the child of that object to fade it in. I did the same thing in reverse basically on the mouseout.

```
            $('.portfolio img').mouseover(function(){
                $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
                $(this).parent().find('img:first').stop().animate({opacity:1}, 800, function() {
                    $(this).parent().next().animate({ height: '+=25px' }, 100, function() {
                        $(this).children().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 100);
                    });
                });
            });

            $('.img_grayscale').mouseout(function(){
                $(this).stop().animate({opacity:0}, 800, function() {
                        $(this).parent().next().children().animate({ opacity: 0 }, 100, function() {
                            $(this).parent().animate({height: '-=25px' }, 100);
                    });
                });
            });
```